# awk rearrange columns in a csv file

Tags: bash, csv, awk

I have a csv file that has the data with 5 columns and i need to rearrange the columns to make the athlete column come first and then all the other columns here is the original csv file named Final.csv

*I pasted the output from libreoffice so this output has no commas and seem like a tsv file but it is a csv file*

```
Trialtime   type    Track   time    Athlete
20170101 07:15:00   Warmup  ABC 85.2    Jon
20170101 07:45:00   Sprint1 ABC 59.44   Jon
20170101 08:30:00   TRIAL   ABC 57.21   Jon
20170101 08:00:00   Warmup  ABC 120.51  Bill
20170101 08:40:05   Sprint1 ABC 61.35   Bill
20170101 09:15:00   Sprint2 ABC 60.08   Bill
20170101 10:30:00   TRIAL   ABC 60.37   Bill
20170101 07:15:00   Warmup  ABC 85.2    Jon
20170101 07:45:00   Sprint1 ABC 59.44   Jon
20170101 08:30:00   TRIAL   ABC 57.21   Jon
20170101 08:00:00   Warmup  ABC 120.51  Bill
20170101 08:40:05   Sprint1 ABC 61.35   Bill
20170101 09:15:00   Sprint2 ABC 60.08   Bill
20170101 10:30:00   TRIAL   ABC 60.37   Bill
```

**and i want to make the athelete coulmn first aso i use this awk command**

```
awk -F, '{print $5,$1,$2,$3,$4}' OFS=, Final.csv > add.csv
```

**It rearranges the coulmns alright but make the data garbled like this**

as you can see there is somehow a extra field is coming on top and making the data unusable

```
Athlete             
    Trialtime   type    Track   time
Jon             
    20170101 07:15:00   Warmup  ABC 85.2
Jon             
    20170101 07:45:00   Sprint1 ABC 59.44
Jon             
    20170101 08:30:00   TRIAL   ABC 57.21
Bill                
    20170101 08:00:00   Warmup  ABC 120.51
Bill                
    20170101 08:40:05   Sprint1 ABC 61.35
Bill                
    20170101 09:15:00   Sprint2 ABC 60.08
Bill                
    20170101 10:30:00   TRIAL   ABC 60.37
```

i have no earthly idea what is going wrong here i have been at it for around 4 hours now, i think i am doing everything right but why the extra space comes ?

Comment: Is the file coming from Windows? Try to remove windows line endings with `sed -i '' 's/\r//' file` before you process it with `awk`.

Comment: no i use ubuntu 16.04

Comment: Can you try the `sed` command? It doesn't harm when there are no Windows line endings in it

Comment: i do not know how to wrok with that i heard awk is better thats what i tried

Comment: Please try `sed 's/\r//' Final.csv | awk -F, '{print $5,$1,$2,$3,$4}' OFS=,`. Does it work?

Comment: Could you please "octal-dump" the first few lines of your file using something like this: `head -n5 <your_input_file_here> | od -c`? You might have spurious character in your file...

Comment: hek2mgl please make your comment an answer it worked perfectly

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, make sure that libreoffice csv export is using UNIX line endings. Problem solved.

---

Well, the `sed` command was good for a quick check if it is really a Windows line ending problem. You can use the following `awk` command which preserves the windows line endings:

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS=","}{sub(/\r$/,"");print $5,$1,$2,$3,$4"\r"}' Final.csv
```

or more elegantly, [as suggested by EdMorton](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45742056/awk-rearrange-columns-in-a-csv-file/45742794?noredirect=1#comment78444854_45742794):

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS=","} {ORS=(sub(/\r$/,"")?"\r":"")RS; print $5,$1,$2,$3,$4}' Final.csv
```

---

If you want to convert to UNIX:

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS=","}{sub(/\r$/,"");print $5,$1,$2,$3,$4}' Final.csv
```

---

Btw, if you want nicely aligned columns in the output, pipe the `awk` command to `column -t`:

```
awk ... | column -t
```

Comment: Consider: `awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS=","} {ORS=(sub(/\r$/,"")?"\r":"")RS; print $5,$1,$2,$3,$4}' Final.csv` for retaining `\r`s in the output if present in the input without having them at the end of the last field during processing. That will ensure any `\r` is removed from the record and final field before you start processing no matter how many fields the input has, won't remove them from anywhere else in the file, and won't cause the record to be recompiled and will reproduce the `\r`s in the output if they were present in the input.

Comment: No that'll work in any awk. What part looks gawk-specific?

Comment: I thought that because POSIX limits `RS` to a single character, the same applies to `ORS`. But looks like this is [not the case](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/utilities/awk.html)

Comment: @EdMorton Btw, when `RS` is limited to a single character, how can `awk` on Windows be POSIX conform? I mean, POSIX does not forbid it, sure.

Comment: Right, in POSIX RS is a single character while ORS is a string and in gawk RS is a multi-char regexp while ORS is a string. In POSIX using an RS of more than one character is undefined behavior so any awk can do whatever it likes with that and still be POSIX compliant. Most non-gawk awks I've used just truncate a multi-char RS after the first character which confuses people as they use `RS="\r\n"` and it LOOKS like it works in some situations but in reality a "\n" will appear at the start of every record since it got chopped off the RS leaving the RS as "\r".

Comment: You mispelled Ed's surname in `as suggested by EdMorten`

Comment: Oh! ... Fixed! :)

Answer (score 1):

[hek2mgl](https://stackoverflow.com/users/171318/hek2mgl)  gave this answer in the comment it worked perfectly it was happening because of line breaks

```
sed 's/\r//' Final.csv | awk -F, '{print $5,$1,$2,$3,$4}' OFS=,
```

Answer (score 1):

```
awk '{nf=$NF; $NF=""; printf("%-7s %-10s %-10s %-8s %0s %s\n",nf,$1,$2,$3,$4,$5)}' file
```

Output:

```
Athlete Trialtime  type       Track    time 
Jon     20170101   07:15:00   Warmup   ABC 85.2
Jon     20170101   07:45:00   Sprint1  ABC 59.44
Jon     20170101   08:30:00   TRIAL    ABC 57.21
Bill    20170101   08:00:00   Warmup   ABC 120.51
Bill    20170101   08:40:05   Sprint1  ABC 61.35
Bill    20170101   09:15:00   Sprint2  ABC 60.08
Bill    20170101   10:30:00   TRIAL    ABC 60.37
Jon     20170101   07:15:00   Warmup   ABC 85.2
Jon     20170101   07:45:00   Sprint1  ABC 59.44
Jon     20170101   08:30:00   TRIAL    ABC 57.21
Bill    20170101   08:00:00   Warmup   ABC 120.51
Bill    20170101   08:40:05   Sprint1  ABC 61.35
Bill    20170101   09:15:00   Sprint2  ABC 60.08
Bill    20170101   10:30:00   TRIAL    ABC 60.37
```